# How to find $P(x)$ here?

Tags: polynomials

> For such polynomial $P(x)$,
>
> $$P(x^4) = ax^8+(b+1)x^5+(ab)x^4+(a-1)x^2 + 2b-2$$
>
> Find the remainder of the division of $P(x^3-3)$ with $x+1$.

We might have to find $P(x)$ first. My attempt is shown below

$$P(x^4) = a(x^4)^2 + (b+1)(x^4)x+(ab)x^4 + (a-1)\dfrac{x^4}{x^2}+2b-2$$

So

$$P(x) = ax^2 +(b+1)x^2 + (ab)x + \color{red}{(a-1)x^{-1}}+2b-2$$

However, the degree of a polynomial should be a natural number. Correspondingly I've gone wrong somewhere.

Regards

Comment: Just must be $b=-1$ and $a=1$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Why is that?

Comment: By the definition of the polynomial. $p(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n$, where $a_0\neq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$P(t) = at^2+(b+1)t^{5/4}+(ab)t+(a-1)t^{1/2} + 2b-2$$ you deduce that $b=-1$ and $a=1$ for $P$ to indeed be a polynomial.

Then the requested remainder is

$$P((-1)^3-3)=(-4)^2-(-4)-4=16.$$

Comment: Could you explain this part a bit: $P((-1)^3-3)=(-4)^2-(-4)-4=16.$?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Maybe there is another way to write $p$ like polynomial without square radicals? I think your reasoning just is total wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: please show me.

Comment: @Enzo: review your theory of division by a linear binomial.

Comment: @Yves Daoust You need to show us that it's impossible. Otherwise, your reasoning is nothing.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: fractional powers never vanish by differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Just should be $b=-1$ and $a=1$.

The rest is smooth.

Let $p(x)=a_0x^{n}+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n,$ where $a_0\neq0.$

Thus, by the given
$$a_0x^{4n}+a_1x^{4n-4}+...+a_n= ax^8+(b+1)x^5+(ab)x^4+(a-1)x^2 + 2b-2.$$
We know that two polynomials are equal iff all coefficients before powers are equal.

Thus, $b+1=0$ and $a-1=0$, which gives
$$p(x)=x^2-x-4.$$

Now, the remainder it's $p(x^3-3),$ where $x=-1$ and since
$$p(-4)=(-4)^2-(-4)-4=16,$$ we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $P$ must be a quadratic polynomial:

$$ P(x) = cx^2+dx+e \implies P(x^4) = cx^8+dx^4+e$$

So $b+1=0$ and $a-1=0$.

Comment: How did we conclude that $p$ must be quadratic polynomial?

Comment: Can it be third degree or more? What about first or less?

Comment: Yes, why not? It can be third degree or more.

Comment: Then I can't help you

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If it was third degree then the leading term of $P(x^4)$ would have $x^{12}$. Same goes for fourth degree and so on.